# How can I add multi custom font in tailwindcss

Tags: css, tailwind-css

eHi, How can I add multi custom font? I want to add two custom font to tailwindcss, but have an issued one of fonts work another not.fonts are in one folder.

I have fontiran.css stylesheet file:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: IRANSans;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 900;
    src: url('../fonts/eot/IRANSansWeb_Black.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/eot/IRANSansWeb_Black.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-8 */
    url('../fonts/woff2/IRANSansWeb_Black.woff2') format('woff2'), /* FF39+,Chrome36+, Opera24+*/
    url('../fonts/woff/IRANSansWeb_Black.woff') format('woff'), /* FF3.6+, IE9, Chrome6+, Saf5.1+*/
    url('../fonts/ttf/IRANSansWeb_Black.ttf') format('truetype');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: IRANSans;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    src: url('../fonts/eot/IRANSansWeb_Bold.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/eot/IRANSansWeb_Bold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-8 */
    url('../fonts/woff2/IRANSansWeb_Bold.woff2') format('woff2'), /* FF39+,Chrome36+, Opera24+*/
    url('../fonts/woff/IRANSansWeb_Bold.woff') format('woff'), /* FF3.6+, IE9, Chrome6+, Saf5.1+*/
    url('../fonts/ttf/IRANSansWeb_Bold.ttf') format('truetype');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: IRANSans;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 500;
    src: url('../fonts/eot/IRANSansWeb_Medium.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/eot/IRANSansWeb_Medium.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-8 */
    url('../fonts/woff2/IRANSansWeb_Medium.woff2') format('woff2'), /* FF39+,Chrome36+, Opera24+*/
    url('../fonts/woff/IRANSansWeb_Medium.woff') format('woff'), /* FF3.6+, IE9, Chrome6+, Saf5.1+*/
    url('../fonts/ttf/IRANSansWeb_Medium.ttf') format('truetype');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: IRANSans;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 300;
    src: url('../fonts/eot/IRANSansWeb_Light.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/eot/IRANSansWeb_Light.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-8 */
    url('../fonts/woff2/IRANSansWeb_Light.woff2') format('woff2'), /* FF39+,Chrome36+, Opera24+*/
    url('../fonts/woff/IRANSansWeb_Light.woff') format('woff'), /* FF3.6+, IE9, Chrome6+, Saf5.1+*/
    url('../fonts/ttf/IRANSansWeb_Light.ttf') format('truetype');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: IRANSans;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 200;
    src: url('../fonts/eot/IRANSansWeb_UltraLight.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/eot/IRANSansWeb_UltraLight.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-8 */
    url('../fonts/woff2/IRANSansWeb_UltraLight.woff2') format('woff2'), /* FF39+,Chrome36+, Opera24+*/
    url('../fonts/woff/IRANSansWeb_UltraLight.woff') format('woff'), /* FF3.6+, IE9, Chrome6+, Saf5.1+*/
    url('../fonts/ttf/IRANSansWeb_UltraLight.ttf') format('truetype');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: IRANSans;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    src: url('../fonts/eot/IRANSansWeb.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/eot/IRANSansWeb.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-8 */
    url('../fonts/woff2/IRANSansWeb.woff2') format('woff2'), /* FF39+,Chrome36+, Opera24+*/
    url('../fonts/woff/IRANSansWeb.woff') format('woff'), /* FF3.6+, IE9, Chrome6+, Saf5.1+*/
    url('../fonts/ttf/IRANSansWeb.ttf') format('truetype');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: iransansdn;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    src: url('../fonts/eot/iransansdnbold.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/eot/iransansdnbold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-8 */
    url('../fonts/woff2/iransansdnbold.woff2') format('woff2'), /* FF39+,Chrome36+, Opera24+*/
    url('../fonts/woff/iransansdnbold.woff') format('woff'), /* FF3.6+, IE9, Chrome6+, Saf5.1+*/
    url('../fonts/ttf/iransansdnbold.ttf') format('truetype');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: iransansdn;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 300;
    src: url('../fonts/eot/iransansdnlight.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/eot/iransansdnlight.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-8 */
    url('../fonts/woff2/iransansdnlight.woff2') format('woff2'), /* FF39+,Chrome36+, Opera24+*/
    url('../fonts/woff/iransansdnlight.woff') format('woff'), /* FF3.6+, IE9, Chrome6+, Saf5.1+*/
    url('../fonts/ttf/iransansdnlight.ttf') format('truetype');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: iransansdn;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    src: url('../fonts/eot/iransansdn.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/eot/iransansdn.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-8 */
    url('../fonts/woff2/iransansdn.woff2') format('woff2'), /* FF39+,Chrome36+, Opera24+*/
    url('../fonts/woff/iransansdn.woff') format('woff'), /* FF3.6+, IE9, Chrome6+, Saf5.1+*/
    url('../fonts/ttf/iransansdn.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

and this stylesheet to compile file:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@import url(fontiran.css);


@tailwind utilities;
```

and for the last step, I add fonts to tailwind.config.js file:

```
module.exports = {
  purge: [],
  theme: {
    fontFamily: {
      displayHead: ['iransansdn', 'sans-serif'],
      body:['IRANSans','sans-serif'],
    },
    extend: {},
  },
  variants: {},
  plugins: [],
}
```

now *font-body* work fine but *font-displayHead* not work, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generated CSS classes are generated with "-" instead of camelCase, so you should use

```
class="font-display-head"
```

Comment: I change the name to display and use `class="display"` but still not work, naming is no a problem.

Comment: If you changed the name to display you should use `class="font-display"` not `class="display"`